# Why unable to do a POST request with data using ajax call?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api, http-post

I am trying to insert data through POSTRequest in clientside code.When the request goes to controller methods i am not able to retrieve the data sent.
Clientside code:

```
function AddUser()
    {         
        var user = { UserID: $('#UidTxt').val, UserName: $('#UnameTxt').val, Password: $('#PwdTxt').val, Email: $('#EmailTxt').val, Address: $('#AddrTxt').val, DOB: $('#DobTxt').val, Phone: $('#PhoneTxt') };
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://localhost:61540/api/UserDetails/AddUser',
            type: 'POST',
            data: JSON.stringify(user),
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success! data is posted/inserted.")
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(xhr.ResponseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Web Api Controller Methods:

```
[System.Web.Http.AcceptVerbs("POST")]
    [ActionName("AddUser")]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpPost]
    [System.Web.Http.HttpOptions]
    public List<UserDetails> AddUser(UserDetail oUserList)
    {
        if (oUserList != null)
        { 
        db.UserDetails.Add(oUserList);
        db.SaveChanges();
        }
        var userList = db.UserDetails.ToList();
        return DTOConverter.ConvertUserDetail(userList);
    }
```

While Debugging,the call hits the controller methods and i find oUserList object is null.
Am i passing the data correctly? correct me if am wrong.
Thanks in advance .

**EDIT:**

```
 function AddUser()
    {
        var UserID = $('#UidTxt').val();
        var UserName= $('#UnameTxt').val(); 
        var Password = $('#PwdTxt').val();
        var Email= $('#EmailTxt').val();
        var Address= $('#AddrTxt').val();
        var DOB = $('#DobTxt').val(); 
        var Phone = $('#PhoneTxt').val();
        var data = 'UserID=' + UserID + '&UserName=' + UserName + '&Password=' + Password + '&Email=' + Email + '&Address=' + Address + '&DOB=' + DOB + '&Phone=' + Phone ;
        $.ajax({ 
            url: 'http://localhost:61540/api/UserDetails/AddUser',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("success! data is posted/inserted.")
            },
            error: function (xhr, status) {
                alert(xhr.ResponseText);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Did you tried to set get all values with get and then add it to one string and passed them to ajax?

Comment: so add var username = UserID: $('#UnameTxt').val();
var password = $('#PwdTxt').val(); etc. Add var data = 'username=' +username+ '&password=' +password+ etc ; In ajax call add data:data, dataType: 'json'. If you get error write here which one.

Comment: Can you post `UserDetails` class implemantation? Does your `AddUser` method have `UserDetail` or `UserDetails` parameter?

Comment: I tried as you said,didn't help.It throws error "undefined". @KondukterCRO

Comment: Yes it has parameters of UserDetails class. @feeeper

Comment: @user3837883 Did you try hardcode your data instead of get values from controls? I ran your code myself with hardcoded values and it works fine for me.

Comment: I need to get values from controls . Hardcoded value works fine for me.

Comment: @user3837883 so first post your form code here. Second, use `.val()` instead of `.val` as @HarishKommuri told. Than use Chrome Developer Tools (Network tab) or firebug for Firefox to catch your request and you can see what data sends to the server

Comment: @feeeper I have added thecode in EDIT section.

Comment: @user3837883 You shouldn't use `JSON.stringify` if your data is a string. And you miss `=` sign between parameter name and it's value.

Comment: You have forgotten equals sign in your data variable. var data = 'UserID=' + UserID + '&UserName=' + UserName + '&Password=' [...]

Comment: I was able to run the code successfully in IE.But fails in chrome and Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your $.ajax function the type attribute POST is missing closing inverted according to code which you have posted and also use val() as @Harish said

Comment: uh sorry for that.I have updated the code.It's fine in my code with inverted commas.

Answer (score 0):

The `val` in javascript is wrong, it correct syntax ix `val()`. Change your javascript like in the below code

```
function AddUser()
{       
    var UserDetail = {
      UserID :$('#UidTxt').val(),
      UserName : $('#UnameTxt').val(),
      Password : $('#PwdTxt').val(),
      Email : $('#EmailTxt').val(),
      Address : $('#AddrTxt').val(),
      DOB : $('#DobTxt').val(),
      Phone :$('#PhoneTxt').val()
   };
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:61540/api/UserDetails/AddUser',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(UserDetail),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("success! data is posted/inserted.")
        },
        error: function (xhr, status) {
            alert(xhr.ResponseText);
        }
    });
}
```

Create a model for `UserDetail`

```
public class UserDetail
{
  public int UserID{get;set;}
  public string Username{get;set;}
  public string Password{get;set;}
  public string Email{get;set;}
  public string Address{get;set;}
  public DateTime DOB{get;set;}
  public int Phone{get;set;}
}
```

Then in the controller

```
public JsonResult  AddUser(UserDetail oUserList)
{
    ..your code
}
```

You culd chabge the variable type according to the variable in the controller. 
Hope this helps

Comment: Can't we pass it as an object?I use the same method for doing a insert in c# code.Now I require to pass the data as an object to controller methods.

Comment: Still the same.Unable to retrieve the value in controller methods.

Comment: Thanks for your response anand. The code works only in IE not on chrome,firefox.Have any idea?

Comment: NO [FromBody] didnt help . I tried in all Non IE browsers oUserList comes null.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103944/discussion-between-anand-and-user3837883).

Comment: i think you need to wrap data to match parameter name in controller's action
 data: JSON.stringify({oUserList:obj}),

Answer (score 0):

As , pointed by other Val() should be used instead of val , If you are trying to submit a form , Instead of JSON try with form.serialize() method and check if you are able to get data on server side .